# HTML5 canvas reference within function

Tags: javascript

The aim is to be able to draw a line starting with `mousedown` and finishing with `mouseup`. In between, the line is drawn onto the canvas with the `draw()` function while `mousemouse`. I need to clear the canvas while the line is dragged.

**JS:**

```
var c = document.getElementById("canvas1");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var isDrawing = false;
var mX, mY, rX, rY;


function InitThis() {


    c.onmousedown = function(e) {
      isDrawing = true;
      mX = e.clientX;
      mY = e.clientY;
      };

    c.onmousemove = function(e) {
        if (isDrawing) {
          rX = e.clientX;
          rY = e.clientY;
          draw();
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
    };

    c.onmouseup = function(e) {
      rX = e.clientX;
      rY = e.clientY;
      isDrawing = false;
  }

}

function draw() {

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(mX,mY);
    ctx.lineTo(rX, rY);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.stroke();

}

InitThis()
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="description" content="[draw lines with mouse]">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas1" width="800" height="900" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
    Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.</canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: canvas is not defined
    at HTMLCanvasElement.InitThis.c.onmousemove (zivuqeyure.js:22:31)
```

How can I reference the canvas inside the function?

Comment: In `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);`, you are referencing `canvas`, which isn't defined.

Comment: `'canvas' !== 'c'`

Comment: @ndugger What do you exactly mean?

Comment: @Cerbrus Canvas is defined, isn't it? There is a canvas and it's clearly defined at the beginning of the code. Can you explain what you meant?

Comment: @alkopop79: Where is `canvas` defined? What line?

Comment: You wrote "you are referencing canvas, which isn't defined." The question is, how can I solve this?

Comment: `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` <-- That line there. Think about it. What is `canvas`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I don't know, that's why I posted my question. I'm a beginner and I just want some help. Can you please help me?

Comment: Replace canvas by c and it would work

Comment: What is unclear about the error message _"`canvas` is not defined"_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referencing a canvas object with the variable “c”.

This is the first line of code.

Later, you try to refer to the “canvas” variable, which is not defined. (You should use “c” instead of “canvas”)

The interpreter doesn’t know that by “canvas” you mean “the canvas object, which is stored in c”.
The interpreter does exactly what you tell it, but you tried to refer to a variable that doesn’t exist.

Comment: Please don't answer typo questions like there. Close-vote them, instead. They're off-topic.